Why is Firefox Snap on Ubuntu 24.04 still tracking `latest/stable/ubuntu-22.04` channel
I upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, and to my surprise I see that Firefox Snap is still tracking the old 22.04 channel:
snap info firefox

...
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-22.04`
...

Why is that? Shouldn't Firefox on 24.04 track:
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04
Maybe it's just a naming issue, but I think it's confusing for end users, like you're running outdated/wrong sourced software.
